# Excel List of values from table?

Tags: excel, formulas, array-formulas

In an excel sheet I have a table like this:

```
    A          B
String 1       0
String 2       0
String 3       7
String 4       0
String 5       0
String 6       2
String 7       0
String 8       4
```

My goal is (**using only formulas**) to obtain a reduced table filtered by the values in column B that are bigger than 0. Something like this:

```
   C          D
String 3      7
String 6      2
String 8      4
```

Taking into account that the values in column B can change dinamically, ¿What's the easiest way to achieve this without VBA or pivot tables?

Comment: Excel has an *Autofilter*. Check it out!

Answer (score 0):

Without using VBA or pivot table, the only way is to write an unique list of column A member, then use the [`SUMIF`](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/sumif.php) function to sum the points (column B of your example) of each one.

Finally you can apply an autofilter: show if value is greater than 0.